# Typoscript: Link around Content Element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I want to use the field "header_link" for a link around a content element. This is my Typoscript:

```
temp.teaserblockContent = CONTENT
temp.teaserblockContent{
   table = tt_content
   select {
      pidInList = this
      orderBy = sorting
      where = colPos = 4
   }
   renderObj < tt_content
   renderObj.stdWrap.typolink {
     parameter =  {field:header_link}
     parameter.insertData = 1
   }
}
```

If I replace `{field:header_link}` with `{tsfe:id}` it works. But not with `{field:header_link}`, even `{field:uid}` is empty. In database, header_link is set correctly. 
How can I access the field values?

tt_content uses gridelements, so a simple 20 = TEXT is not possible.

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
    1 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
    1 {
        columns {
           10 < .default
           10.wrap = <div class="col-md-12">|</div>
        }
    } 
    2 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
    2 {...}
}
```

Comment: Did you found a solution for that? I have exactly same problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
parameter.field = header_link
```

or

```
parameter.data = field:header_link
```

EDIT: Try to add header_link to select.selectFields = header_link ... but I think by default if selectFields is not set, every field should be selected.

Comment: Yes, I tried 100 combinations of field and dataWrap and stdWrap without result, I think its a logical error

Answer (score 0):

I tested your typoscript setup and it works. Maybe it would help if you tell us the used TYPO3 version and what all this has to do with gridelements.